# ipython qtconsole starts wrong python environment

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, jupyter

I'm using Anaconda on MacOS 10.11.6.

After installing anaconda (python 2.7) and doing

```
conda create -n python3Conda python=3 anaconda
source activate python3Conda
```

my prompt changes as expected:

```
(python3Conda) lhcgeneva:
```

However, doing

```
jupyter qtconsole
```

starts python 2.7.

I tried installing anaconda with a python 3.5 root version, but still, after creating my new virtual environment `python3Conda` and installing some packages, I cannot load these packages, after starting `jupyter qtconsole`, indicating that the console started the root python, instead of the newly created virtual environment.

Comment: `jupyter qtconsole --kernel=python3Conda `?

Comment: Also, run `jupyter kernelspec list` to make sure you have a kernel set up for your `python3Conda` installation.

Comment: Thanks for that, turns out there were old files in home/Library/jupyter, deleting the folder solved the problem.

Comment: @Abdou huh! that old kernel was using `python.exe` instead of `pythonw.exe` and no matter what combination of `cwp.py` and `python` or `pythonw` I was using, the damn console was popping up! Changed the json file and now it is fixed.